# Reduce lag in angularjs UI

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I'm trying to implement (or rather improve) a slider made with angular directives.
The slider has a structure like this:

- div

  - div with the draggable slider (left:percent)
  - div with the progress bar area (width:percent)
- div

  - input box with validation that displays the value (percentage in this case)

One of these sliders also calls a server function to see if a certain date is available and displays the next available date inside the input field.
Another part of the screen shows all the values from all these sliders, dynamically.

I want the slider part and maybe the progress area to be updated instantly, not only on scope.$apply. The other dependencies and validation can be updated later.

To get the slider value I listen on mouse drag and mouse click and compare the mouse event X position with the slider bounding box, calculate the percentage and set it to the scope which gets applied to the template.

This above works really fast when nothing is coupled to the scope value, but as soon as I start adding watchers it gets really slow.

I've tried setting the css directly but this does not get applied before the scope is applied:

```
link:....
  var sliderDiv = element.find('.slider-handle');
  var progressDiv = element.find('.progress-bar');

updateSlider().....
  sliderDiv.css('left', ''+percent+'%');
  progressDiv.css('width', ''+percent+'%');
```

**Is this the right pattern to use?**

I need to do validation on fields, enable or disable stuff selectively, have the sliders tied to values that can change.

**Can CSS/DOM operations be applied immediately in angular directives?**

Everything I try gets applied only when the scope is 'digested'. I know this is an anti-pattern but I'm willing to make that trade-off.

** Can at least have Angular partially consume the scope? **

I've tried setting a separate value for the sliders only and have only that value applied to the scope but it does not seem to work, the scope seems to be consumed only once.

```
        scope.$apply(new function(){
          scope.tempValue = value;
        });
```

Playing with $timeout or _.debounce or _.throttle did not yield any results, it only made the perceived performance worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will resolve the exact issues you're experiencing (it may relate to code not provided here) but I had been experiencing similar when trying to implement a slider with Angular.

To solve the problem I ended up coding my own (**[sliderBar.js](http://sw4.github.io/sliderBar.js/)**) and then implementing it as follows (example only):

```
// whatever your controller is
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {        
  // wait for the document to be ready
  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
     // define scope variable
     $scope.sliderVal=0;
     // create slider
     $('#elementToMakeSlider').sliderBar({  
       // define change event of slider
       onChange:function(value){
         // apply slider value to scope
         $scope.sliderVal=val;
       }
     });
  });    
}]);
```

Depending on the nature of your code/requirement you may need to wrap the onChange function contents thus:

```
     $('#elementToMakeSlider').sliderBar({  
       onChange:function(value){
         $timeout(function() {
           $scope.sliderVal=val;
         });
       }
     });
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this already but it makes the UI seems sluggish because it queues all the requests and then digests them. So if you move the slider fast back and forth and then stop, the input fields catch up for some time with the updates. They should ideally show only the last update, like debounce does, except I cannot use debounce without calling $timeout before.

Comment: If you look at the methods of the slider- there is one `onSet` which ONLY fires when the slider has finished changing. You can use this to set your scope variable and the onChange method to do any GUI updates, this will stop Angular being flooded with unnecessary digest items.

Comment: That would fix the issue but the client wants the updates to be visible and I think that's also good UI practice. I've added a debounce for 300ms which does the job but it's still not ok because as soon as the fields are validated/updated it slows the fast UI updates as well.

Comment: I set your answer as accepted since no one else gave any advice on this the advice is ok for anyone coming later to read this.I was still looking for a way to force CSS/DOM updates without having to $digest stuff but for now this will do.